# Cancel a CSS3 animation when anchor is visited

Tags: css

I want to infinitely pulse the background colour of an identified anchor with CSS animation, and get rid of the animation altogether (= make the anchor look like other anchors) when it's visited.

I have a working animation but I can't get the :visited part to work, basically I fail to cancel the animation.

Here's the code I use http://jsfiddle.net/elddifsj/cKeSV/

P.S. I do *not* want a javascript solution.

Comment: Can you show us your working CSS animation code?

Comment: show us your styles! this is a good question

Comment: i don't have a solution for your specific example, but i did manage to turn it off temporarily using :target http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/cKeSV/9/  hope that helps. i wanna see an answer to this

Answer (score 0):

I'm told that it's not possible because of the changes recently made to [:visited to protect privacy](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/).
It should still be possible since only color changes are allowed and I only change the color, but it doesn't work.